# Text replace in VBA code of Excel files

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, office-interop

we have several tens of macro enabled excel files, each of those contains few VBA modules and in each of those modules there are SQL server names and userid/passwords of the sql login.

I wonder if I could write some kind of C# utility which loads those files one by one and either with .NET-Office Interop. or any other approach replace those strings with something else... just because I have to repoint all those VBA macros to another server name and to use another sql login name and password... I really wouldn't like to do this replacement by hand
:( :( :(

thanks!

Comment: + 1 Good Question :) I have VBA Code ready would that help or do you want a C# code specifically? If you want C# then I will have to amend it and test it in C# before I post it.

Comment: VBA code running standalone is also ok, standalone I mean either is VBScript or in a separated excel file, how do you then pass the filename(s) to search and replace in? If you share your VBA sure I will vote it as answer does not have to be 100% or only C# and .NET :)

Comment: Voting is not a concern. :) Yes, it will be a separate Excel File which will let you choose a folder and then the code will replace relevant text in all the VBA Module in all excel file in that folder.

Comment: Quick question. Will the VBA Files have password?

Comment: Ok My code is ready. Can you confirm the above? And also the Excel version that you are using

Comment: If you're going to do some clean-up, it might be a good idea to use a DSN to specify your database connection, that way you don't have to worry about changing this next time the server address/username/password changes.

Comment: no, files are not pwd protected. yes, DSN and integrated security would surely be better not server name and userId/pwd in each file.... :) good idea!

Comment: `userId/pwd in each file.` Hmm That could be a concern. I am posting a code for unprotected files. i am sure you can update it for protected files?

Comment: userid/pwd are simply text to be replaced, not needed to open the excel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To begin With

Sorry for taking some time in posting but I was creating a UI for it so that it not only helps you but anyone else who comes looking for the same functionality.

You need to first enable `Trust Access to the VBA project Object model`

Open Excel and Click on File Tab | Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings | Macro Settings

Enable macro and click on `Trust access to Visual Basic projects`

[image]

Next In VBA Editor

Click on Tool | Options and under the "Editor" Tab select the checkbox `Require Variable Declaration`

[image]

**Next Download the Sample file from [here](http://wikisend.com/download/139946/Davide%20Piras%20Find%20And%20Replace%20Utility%20Ver%201.0.xlsm) and simply press the `Run` Button In Sheet1 to launch the userform as shown below.**

Simple select the folder which has **ONLY** Excel Files. Enter the relevant info and click on `Start Replace` and you are done :)

[image]

**Code Used**

**Sheet1 Code Area**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

**Userform Code Area**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Ret
    Ret = BrowseForFolder
    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
    TextBox1.Text = Ret
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strPath As String, strfile As String
    Dim strToReplaceWith As String, strToReplace As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim VBE As Object

    strPath = TextBox1.Text & "\"

    strfile = Dir(strPath)

    While strfile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strfile)

        Set VBE = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

        If VBE.VBComponents.Item(1).Properties("HasPassword").Value = False Then
            If VBE.VBComponents.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 1 To VBE.VBComponents.Count
                    VBE.VBComponents.Item(i).Activate

                    If VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines > 0 Then
                        For j = 1 To VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
                            If InStr(1, VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1), TextBox2.Text, vbTextCompare) Then
                                strToReplace = VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1)
                                strToReplaceWith = Replace(strToReplace, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
                                VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.ReplaceLine j, strToReplaceWith
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If

        wb.Close True

        strfile = Dir
    Wend

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

'~~> Function to pop the browse folder dialog
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    '~~> Create a file browser window at the default folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    '~~> Set the folder to that selected.  (On error in case cancelled)
    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Destroy the Shell Application
    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**MORE SNAPSHOTS**

[image]

File Whose code needs to be replaced before the macro is Run

[image]

After the macro is run

[image]

**EDIT**

**ALTERNATIVE FILE DOWNLOAD LOCATION**

In case the above wikisend link dies, the file can be downloaded from [here](http://sdrv.ms/KEiGMT)

Comment: Idea is good, I get an invalid ordinal error, will debug and fix, thanks so much!!

Comment: Which Line do you get the error in? Comment the line which says `On Error GoTo Whoa`

Comment: Two things as mentioned in my post above `1)` Trust Access to the VBA project Object model `2)` Folder should have Only Excel Files `3)` I cant think of any other code line which can give you the error. I tested it completely before posting the answer.

Comment: If VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines > 0 Then

Comment: +1 good one.
I would advise to revert back the VBA settings once you are done with the task to avoid virus attacks. :)

Comment: Good Suggestion Pradeep! :) @DavidePiras: What is the value of `i`? Also manually check the Erroring Excel File. You can get the name of the file using `?wb.Name` in the Immediate window...

Comment: @DavidePiras: : Ok I found the reason :) Open Excel. Go to the VBA Editor then click on Tools ~~> Options. Under Editor Tab, select "Require Variable Declaration" Now it will be ok :) Updated the above post with screenshot

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you create a config file which includes your server names and credentials.
Then you add a module to each of your Excel files that parses this config file at startup and fills global variables with it. You just have to adjust the variables for the server name etc. in all your VBA modules to the new global variables.

This way you can change your access data any time you like just by editing or replacing the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this way of solving your problem. You can create separate vba or vbscript project which will load all the spreadsheets one by one, exporting contents of their vba projects to separate text files. Then you can load those text files and perform string replacements. Afterwards, you can import text files back to spreadsheet as a vba project components (by simple reverting of export process).

You can use this code like this one for exporting the components:

```
Public Sub ExportAppSrcs(targetWb as Workbook)
Dim wb As Workbook, Component As Object, Suffix As String, fileName As String

Set wb = targetWb
    For Each Component In wb.VBProject.VBComponents

        Select Case Component.Type
            Case 1                  'modul
                Suffix = ".bas"
            Case 2                  'class modul
                Suffix = ".cls"
            Case 3                  'form
                Suffix = ".frm"
            Case 100                'dokument
                Suffix = ".xwk"
            Case Else
                Suffix = ""
        End Select

        If Suffix <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            fileName = wb.Path & "\spreadsheet.xlsm.src\" & Component.name & Suffix
            Component.Export fileName
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```